# SQL - Finding common rows based on a column (intersect)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Given the following table:

**InstalledApps**

```
MachineName | AppName | Version
-------------------------------
machine01   | App01   | 1.1
machine01   | App02   | 1.0
machine01   | App03   | 1.5
machine02   | App04   | 2.0
machine02   | App02   | 1.0
machine02   | App01   | 1.1
machine03   | App06   | 7.9.9
machine03   | App01   | 1.1
machine03   | App07   | 11.5
machine03   | App02   | 1.0
```

I need to select `Apps` which are common to given "n" machines. It's an intersect between "n" sets. However, I'm having a hard time coming up with a decent query.

I know that I can do something like this:

```
SELECT AppName, Version 
FROM InstalledApps 
WHERE MachineName = 'machine01'

INTERSECT

SELECT AppName, Version 
FROM InstalledApps 
WHERE MachineName = 'machine02'
```

That will give me

```
AppName | Version
------------------
App01   | 1.1
App02   | 1.0
```

However, is there a way I can do it without having to know the number of machines upfront? Something like

```
SELECT...... 
FROM InstalledApps 
WHERE MachineName IN ('machine01',...'machine99')
```

Comment: Can there be duplicate entries of `(MachineName, AppName, Version)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do it for the general case:

```
SELECT AppName, Version, COUNT(DISTINCT(MachineName)) AS MachineCount
FROM InstalledApps
GROUP BY
  AppName, Version
HAVING
  COUNT(DISTINCT(MachineName)) > 1
```

Comment: Looks like your `GROUP BY` clause is slightly off (should be "AppName, Version" instead of "MachineName"), but otherwise this seems the most sensible answer to the question...

Comment: Also, to address the asker's (implied?) desire to only do this for certain specific machine names, you could add a `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Row_Number` function and `Partition` the Data with Machine Name

```
Select AppName, [Version] From 
(
    Select Row_Number() Over(Partition By MachineName Order by AppName) RowId, * 
    From InstalledApps
)K
Where K.RowId = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parametrize the IN query

```
Declare @value varchar(max)
Declare @sql varchar(max)
select @value = 'machine1,machine2,machine3'
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT * FROM InstalledApps  WHERE MachineName in (' + @value+ ')'

 exec sp_executeSQL @sql
```

Or you can even use a sub query to get all the values

```
SELECT * FROM InstalledApps WHERE MachineName in (SELECT MachineName FROM InstalledApps    group by MachineName HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(MachineName)) > 1)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. given machine01 and machine02, I need to get the applications which installed on both machines, excluding anything that's only on machine01 or machine02.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a group by.  Assuming there are no duplicate machines for a given app in the InstalledApps table:

```
select apps
from InstalledApps
group by apps
having sum(case when machine in (<list of machines>) then 1 else 0 end) = <number of machines>
```

If you have duplicate apps on the machines:

```
select apps
from (select distinct apps, machine from InstalledApps) ia
group by apps
having sum(case when machine in (<list of machines>) then 1 else 0 end) = <number of machines>
```

And, I'm thinking that if you don't want to count the number of machines, then you might need to use dynamic SQL or store the machine names in a temporary table.