# SQL Server can you use EXCEPT or INTERSECT and ignore a column?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, intersect

Here's my question,

```
CREATE TABLE
    #table1(ID int, Fruit varchar(50), Veg varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #table1 (ID,Fruit,Veg)
VALUES (1,'Apple', 'Potato')

CREATE TABLE
    #table2(ID int, Fruit varchar(50), Veg varchar(50))
INSERT INTO #table2 (ID,Fruit,Veg)
VALUES (2,'Apple', 'Potato')

SELECT * FROM #table1 INTERSECT SELECT * FROM #table2
```

I have two tables and I want to find rows which are the same in both, but both tables have different and unrelated ID columns. Is there any way to use INTERSECT or EXCEPT on two tables, but ignore the ID in the comparison?

I need to keep the ID's on the returned rows, so on the example above, two rows would be returned, one with ID = 1 and another with ID=2

If anything other than the ID's is different, then nothing would be returned.

Thanks!

Comment: If the tables contain different and unrelated ID columns, why are you using SELECT *? If you just list Fruit,Veg it should work fine, right? Otherwise you need to determine which ID should show when a Fruit/Veg pair appears in both tables...

Comment: or he could show both, correct?

Comment: @Abe with Intersect? How?

Comment: No sorry, I guess I was thinking about doing it with a JOIN.

Comment: @Abe right, you can do it in other ways, but not with INTERSECT.

Comment: You can, when compensate mismatch columns, use a result from a except/intersect to join with a new query using CTE. Try google for except intersect together with cte and you may find a way forward on the problem.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10818067/6651

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with `INTERSECT`. Maybe with a join instead?

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t1.veg, t1.fruit
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2
ON t1.veg = t2.veg AND t1.fruit = t2.fruit
```